# Is it safe to pass Task as method parameter?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

Consider the following code:

```
public class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Generate();
    }

    static void Generate() {
        Task t = null;
        t = Task.Run(() => {
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
            myClass.ContinueTask(t);
        });
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public class MyClass {

    public void ContinueTask(Task t) {
        t.ContinueWith(x => {
            Console.WriteLine("Continue here...");
        });
    }
}
```

Is it safe to pass t as parameter as so or is it better to directly start a new task inside MyClass?

Comment: That doesn't look safe - in that, there's a small chance that the inner task has started and already reached the call to `Read` *before* the assignment to `t` takes place.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever what is the way to avoid that? I'm using ContinueWith which sounds like you must have the object itself to continue to do something with it.

Comment: This seems like it's almost recursive. Unless I'm missing something this is saying to continue the parse after the read which requires the parse as part of the read.

Comment: And, in fact, it fails to compile because of the definite assignment rules.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this compiles perfectly

Comment: What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: @Enigmativity there's no recursion here the task first waits for a reader to be available and then it parses a document with the same task as a continuation action

Comment: You should be getting Error [CS0165](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y7h161d.aspx) on that `Read` line, since nothing has definitely assigned `t` before that point. (Ah, I see you've *now* added a `= null` assignment. That wasn't previously present)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever t is null initially

Comment: @Chris - I said "almost recursive". I meant it in the sense that each function needs the other to complete first.

Comment: @Chris - Your `Read` method can't compile. The signature is wrong as it stands.

Comment: Why the lock? The continuation runs on its own thread and doesn't (shouldn't) affect any global state.

Comment: @Chris - great, you've now silenced the compiler error. The *race* that was exposed by that compiler error (that I'd spotted in my first comment also) is still present.

Comment: @Chris - I'm struggling to get this code to compile. Can you please post code that will compile when we copy and paste into our dev environments please?

Comment: @Chris are you trying to do a producer/consumer scenario? You may want to look into [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I think you should consider using an ActionBlock to simplify this code and replace Readers, sleeping. The ActionBlock provides an input buffer (to use instead of `Readers`) and executes an Action on each input (to replace the entire `Read` method). The action is executed on a separate thread so there is no need to juggle Tasks

Comment: Using TryDequeue without checking its return value is a huge mistake. Right now there is no guarantee whatsoever that `x.Read(container, t)` won't throw a NullReferenceException. Checking `IsEmpty` before the `TryDequeue` **does not guarantee** that the collection won't be empty when `TryDequeue` is hit.

Comment: @Joren Panagiotis Thanks! :)

Ned I'm using ConcurrentQueue<T>

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Just to add-in : I have the scenario of Multiple consumers single producer, not really sure if that's gonna work.

Comment: @Chris This isn't obvious either from the original or the edited question. It's difficult to give an appropriate answer when the intent of the question is lost in implementation details. The DataFlow library provides a [Broadcast block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx#predefined_types) that could be useful. This won't be useful in a notification scenario though where clients come and go. In this case Reactive Extensions may be more appropriate. What is your specific scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unsafe because `t` might not be assigned at the point where it is used. In fact this is a data race.

Even if you fixed that it would be bad architecture. Why does `ContinueTask` need to know that it is continuing with something. This is a not a concern that should be located here. `ContinueTask` should perform it's work assuming that its antecedent has completed already.

It's hard to tell what you are trying to accomplish. What's wrong with sequencing your code like this:?

```
static async Task Generate() {
    var t = Task.Run(() => {
     //... other code ...
    });

    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    await t;
    myClass.ContinueTask();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

`await` is perfect for sequencing tasks.

> reusing the Task object

What do you mean by that? A task cannot be reused. It cannot run twice. All that your `ContinueWith` does is logically wait for the antecedent and then run the lambda. Here, the task serves as an event basically.

`ContinueWith` does not modify the task it is being called on. It creates a new task.

Comment: @Chris can you say what specifically was helpful about this answer? I did not fully understand the problem that you were trying to solve.

Comment: Didn't check the documentation on ContinueWith. Calling this method ConitnueWith on a task makes sense if it's the same object that performs the action ( at least to me ) thus calling ConitnueWith makes sense to conitnue the work of the previous task ( the same object Task )

Comment: Yeah, tasks are kind of immutable. Immutability is especially helpful in a multi-threaded setting. Also, prefer await over ContinueWith. It's easier to use although pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I've reduced your code down to this example:

```
public Task<int> Parse()
{
    Task<int> t = null;
    t = Task.Run(() => this.Read(t));
    return t;
}

public Task<int> Read(Task<int> t)
{
    return t.ContinueWith(v => 42);
}
```

I think that has the same underlying structure.

This causes a dead-lock. I suspect your code does too. So I think it's unsafe.

Comment: He's not returning `t`.

Comment: @usr - Cricky, he's changed his code. Originally he was returning `t`.

Comment: @usr initially there was a return t statement. Causing a deadlock is indeed a problem but that wasn't the point of my question. The whole point was about reusing the Task object.